# Add Infinite Scroll to Ajax Loaded Category Query

Tags: loop, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

**Update: This has been resolved. See update below.**

Following a few different online tutorials, I've managed to create a function to modify my post display via Ajax based on a category selected from a drop-down menu.

I'd now like to add Infinite Scroll to the Ajax loaded content, and I can't seem to figure out what to do for that.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Here are my php functions:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
    // Register and enqueue script
    wp_register_script('afp_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

    // localize script
    wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), 
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

function wp_infinitepaginate() {
    // Verify nonce
    $nonce = $_POST['afp_nonce'];   
    if ( !isset( $nonce ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'afp_nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Permission denied');

    if (is_front_page()) { 
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    } else {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    }
    $cat = $_POST['val'];
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $cat,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    query_posts($args);
    get_template_part('custom-loop');

    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');    // if user not logged in
```

Here is the JS I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery("#la-chooser").change(function() {
        loadArticlebyCat(this.value);
    });

    function loadArticlebyCat(cat){

        data = {
            action: 'infinite_scroll', 
            val: cat,
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            type:'post',
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
                jQuery("#tb-ajax-content").html( data );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( XMLHttpRequest );
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( MLHttpRequest );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( errorThrown );
                jQuery("#tb-ajax-content").html( 'No posts found' );
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

});
```

Here's the category drop-down filter:

```
Filter by Category: <select id="la-chooser" style="padding:5px 10px;margin-left:5px;">
    <option value="">All Categories</option>
        <?php
            $categories =  get_categories();
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $option = '<option value="'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
                $option .= $category->cat_name;
                $option .= '</option>'."\n";
                echo $option;
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update ... Here's the Final Code That Worked for Me**

This may not be perfect, but it seems to be working well for me with no errors. Feel free to add any suggestions for improvement if you have any.

**JS Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var count = 2;

    jQuery("#la-chooser").change(function() {
        loadArticlebyCat(this.value);
    });

    function loadArticlebyCat(cat){

        data = {
            action: 'infinite_scroll', 
            val: cat,
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            type:'post',
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {
                jQuery("#tb-ajax-content").html( data );
                jQuery('#infinitBtn span').html('Load More Entries');
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( XMLHttpRequest );
                count = 2;
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( MLHttpRequest );
                console.log( textStatus );
                console.log( errorThrown );
                jQuery("#tb-ajax-content").html( 'No posts found' );
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    jQuery('#infinitBtn').click(function(){
        loadArticle(count);
        count++;
        return false;
    });

    function loadArticle(pageNumber) {

        var cat = jQuery("#la-chooser").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            type:'POST',
            data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + "&loop_file=loop&val="+ cat +"&afp_nonce="+afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            success: function(html) {
                if(html=="") {
                    jQuery('#infinitBtn span').html('All Entries Loaded');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#infinitBtn span').html('Load More Entries');
                }
                jQuery("#tb-ajax-content").append(html);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

});
```

---

**WordPress Functions**

Please note I'm using this in a child theme, so you would likely want to use get template directory uri instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri if you're not using a child theme.

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {

    // Register and enqueue script
    wp_register_script('afp_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

    // localize script
    wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ), 
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ));

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

function wp_infinitepaginate() {

    // Verify nonce
    $nonce = $_POST['afp_nonce'];   
    if ( !isset( $nonce ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'afp_nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Permission denied');

    $paged = $_POST['page_no'];
    $cat = $_POST['val'];
    $args = array(
        'category_name' => $cat,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '6',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    query_posts($args);
    get_template_part('custom-loop');
    wp_reset_query();

    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_infinite_scroll', 'wp_infinitepaginate');    // if user not logged in
```

---

**Main Loop Code With Drop-Down Category Selector**

```
<div class="latest-article-chooser clearfix">
    <h1>Latest Blog Posts</h1>
    <p>
        <span>Filter Posts by Category:</span> <select id="la-chooser">
            <option value="">All Categories</option>
                <?php
                    $categories =  get_categories();
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $option = '<option value="'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
                        $option .= $category->cat_name;
                        $option .= ' ('.$category->count.')';
                        $option .= '</option>'."\n";
                        echo $option;
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="tb-ajax-content">

<?php
    if (is_front_page()) { 
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    } else {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    }
    $count = 1;
    query_posts(array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '6',
        'paged' => $paged,
    ));

    get_template_part('custom-loop');
?>

</div>

<div class="post-clear"></div>

<a class="button sc blue" href="#" id="infinitBtn"><span>Load More Entries</span></a>
```

---

**Custom Loop File (custom-loop.php)**

There are some theme-specific functions included here so you'd want to replace them with your own functions (or native WordPress functions).

```
<?php 
    $count = 1;
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemprop="blogPost">

        <div class="entry-wrap">

            <div class="entry-media">
                <?php 
                    if ( tb_option('medium_thumb') ) { 
                        themebeagle_medium_thumbnail(); 
                    } else {
                        themebeagle_large_thumbnail(); 
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="entry-container">

                <header class="entry-header">
                    <?php 
                        themebeagle_entry_title();
                        themebeagle_entry_meta(); 
                    ?>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
                    <?php themebeagle_excerpt(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            </div> <!-- .entry-container -->

            <footer class="entry-footer">
                <?php themebeagle_entry_meta_bottom(); ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

        </div> <!-- .entry-wrap -->

    </article> <!-- article.post -->

<?php 
    $count = $count + 1; 
    endwhile; 
    endif; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```